# How to get rid of a query string

Tags: javascript, url-routing, browser-history

SOLVED

I have a kinda stupid issue. I can't get rid of the query string !! Once I put it into the history, I can't find how to remove it.

I have a React app with navigation (Universal Router). I don't believe it is related to the library I use, but rather to a bad use of the URL and History API.

I have a list of users, and each has a number. I have an input form to enter the number. I append this as a query string in the form `/users?nb=1`. This url is submitted to a resolver that searches in an array of paths.
The action code corresponding to the `/users` path has a function that reads if a query string is present. If yes, extract the number and push the new path `/users/1`.
This almost works: I push in fact `/users/1?nb=1`..

Note: I can of course directly push `/users/1` without a query string but this is an exercise.

What is the trick?? [EDIT]: override the key `search:""`

EDIT:
https://codesandbox.io/s/universal-router-mobx-demo-jg3um?file=/src/NavBar.js

1- the emitting function, creates the query string

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let query = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.currentTarget));
    const {pathname, search} = window.location 
    const qstring = new URLSearchParams(search);
    for (const k in query){ qstring.append(k, query[k])};
    history.push({ pathname, search: "?" + qstring });
  }
```

1b - vs a "normal" link

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push({ pathname: e.target.pathname });
  };
```

2- the conditional path (for the query string)

```js
const searchString = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const id = searchString.get("nb");
if (id) { return { redirect: `/users/${id}` } }
```

3- the resolving

```js
const page = await router.resolve({ pathname: location.pathname });
if (page.redirect) {
    return history.push({ pathname: page.redirect, search: "" });
 }                                                  ^^^!
return render(<React.StrictMode>{page}</React.StrictMode>, root);
```

The pb is solved by adding **search:""** which removes the trailing query string.

Comment: Edited @Ouroborus

Comment: I notice you're using `{ pathname: "?" + qstring }` in your code fragment "1.". When you use `history.push()`, you're not restricted to just the `pathname` option. You also have (among other things) a `search` option available. I think you'd need to add the option `search: ''` as needed when you're processing your returned redirect so that it knows it should clear the query.

Comment: indeed, did the trick! Thanks! I edited with the answer

Comment: @Ouroborus and OP would someone of you mind to post the answer as an answer? Just for the spirit of SO! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

So as @Ouroborus showed, you just need to add  `search:''`  in the returned url from the resolver to override the previous query string:

```js
history.push({pathname: page.redirect, search:""})
```